# Vuejs Cannot read property 'use' of undefined error

Tags: vue.js, datatables, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to integrate a Datatable plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datatable) in my Vue application and I'm getting an error in my console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined
    at eval (vuejs-datatable.js?b015:1)
    at Object.eval (vuejs-datatable.js?b015:1)
    at eval (vuejs-datatable.js:4)
    at Object../node_modules/vuejs-datatable/dist/vuejs-datatable.js (app.js:10170)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
    at fn (app.js:89)
    at eval (selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/views/tables/data-table.vue:2)
    at Object../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/views/tables/data-table.vue (app.js:1438)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
    at fn (app.js:89)
```

My dataTable.vue file:

```
<template lang="html">

  <section class="data-table">
   <datatable :columns="columns" :data="rows"></datatable>
  </section>

</template>

<script lang="js">
import Vue from 'vue'
import DatatableFactory from 'vuejs-datatable'
export default {
  name: 'DatatablePage'
}
Vue.use(DatatableFactory)
</script>
```

And whenever i try to use 'Vue.use(PluginName)' when integrating a plugin, i get the similar error. I'm new to VueJS. Is there anything i need to do ?

Comment: What if you move ```Vue.use ...``` to above the ```export default```?

Comment: I'll get an error saying 'Unexpected token' and the app fails to compile

Comment: What is the version of VueJs you're using, it's greater than 2.3?

Comment: getting the same error with the same plugin (vuejs-datatable), double-checked plugin is added before the main Vue instance is initialized as per @Psidom 's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following in weback.config.js seemed to do the trick:

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            ...
            'vuejs-datatable': 'vuejs-datatable/dist/vuejs-datatable.esm.js',
            ...
        }
    },
}
```

Based on discussion here:

https://github.com/pstephan1187/vue-datatable/issues/50

Answer (score 3):

You need to add plugin before your main `Vue` instance is initialized; See [using vue plugins here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html), which says:

> Use plugins by calling the Vue.use() global method. ***This has to be
> done before you start your app by calling `new Vue()`***.

For your case, move

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.use(DatatableFactory)
```

to your `main.js`, so it looks like:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.use(DatatableFactory)

// some other code

new Vue({
...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error in my vue-app.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
...some more imports here....

Vue.use(VueRouter);

...
```

The error was `cannot read property 'use' of undefined`. Which means, it had a problem with reading Vue. I checked my `package.json` and `package-lock.json` (for whether I installed in my local). Everything seemed ok. I had both Vue and Vue-router.

Deleting `node_modules` and **re-installing worked for me**.

Comment: How can you delete and re-install node_modules folder from project ? Can you explain please ?

Comment: I tried what you said but the problem is not solved